# Pythonic way to produce a list from nested dictionary

Tags: python, python-2.7, dictionary, iteration, list-comprehension

working in Python 2.7, I have a nested dictionary with some quote data, from which I would like to produce a list of successfully constructed quotes. Currently, here is how I do this:

```
result = []
for nameStr, nameData in dataTbl.iteritems():
    for valueDate, record in nameData.iteritems():
        quote = histRecordToQuote(securitiesDict = securitiesDict,
                                  nameStr        = nameStr,
                                  valueDate      = valueDate,
                                  record         = record)
        if quote:
            result.append(quote)
```

Is there a more Pythonic way to do this? I have a hunch we can do faster or clearer with a list comprehension. The function `histRecordToQuote()` returns `None` when it cannot construct a quote due to a data error. You can suggest a different signature, I'll be happy to rewrite it for clearer/faster code.

Thank you very much.

**EDIT**

An example of a dictionary structure:

```
{'IBM':  {'20140215':2.53, '20140216':2.55},
 'MSFT': {'20140213':2.45, '20140216':0.},
 'AMZN': {'20140212':0., '20140214':2.59}}
```

The parameter `securitiesDict` is external, it is needed for constructing the `Quote` class inside `histRecordToQuote()`.

The output from `histRecordToQuote()` would return `None` for 0-price records and construct valid `Quote` from the rest.

```
Quote('IBM', '20140215', 2.53)
Quote('IBM', '20140216', 2.55)
Quote('MSFT', '20140213', 2.45)
None
Quote('AMZN', '20140214', 2.59)
None
```

My final output needs to be the list of valid quotes:

```
[Quote('IBM', '20140215', 2.53),
Quote('IBM', '20140216', 2.55),
Quote('MSFT', '20140213', 2.45),
Quote('AMZN', '20140214', 2.59)]
```

Comment: can you provide a clear example of the dict structure?

Comment: and the desired output?

Comment: @JDavidSmith i put in the expected function output and what i would like in the final output as well. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve the same with a nested comprehension:

```
[ quote for quote in
    (histRecordToQuote(securitiesDict = securitiesDict,
                       nameStr        = nameStr,
                       valueDate      = valueDate,
                       record         = record)
      for nameStr, nameData in dataTbl.iteritems()
        for valueDate, record in nameData.iteritems())
    if quote ]
```

Comment: Will this be any faster?

Comment: List comps are somewhat faster than accumulators, but don't expect a blinding difference. Profile it and try!

Comment: Not speed should be the incentive here (it might be frustrating then).  Using comprehensions binds you in a tight corset which prevents a lot of otherwise possible errors.  The Pythonic way has practical advantages besides speed.